# NameError: uninitialized constant DeviseMultipleTokenAuthDevice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

Hello Programmers & Developers!!!, I'm facing a problem in `rails console` when I tried to access `DeviseMultipleTokenAuthDevice` then I'm getting the following error :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
2.2.4 :001 > DeviseMultipleTokenAuthDevice
NameError: uninitialized constant DeviseMultipleTokenAuthDevice
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@devise_demo/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@devise_demo/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@devise_demo/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@devise_demo/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@devise_demo/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2.2.4 :002 >
```

Following gems I'm using in my project for user authentication

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_multiple_token_auth'
```

Following are the tables in my record :

```
2.2.4 :002 > p ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
["schema_migrations", "users", "devise_multiple_token_auth_devices"]
 => ["schema_migrations", "users", "devise_multiple_token_auth_devices"] 
2.2.4 :003 >
```

**For more info you can follow these links :**

- [Source from where I followed the instruction](https://github.com/JoshJuncker/DeviseMultipleTokenAuth)
- [My Github repo link for project source](https://github.com/vishalnagda1/devise_demo/tree/staging)

Other required information
**Ruby Version** `2.2.4`
**Rails Version** `4.2.0`
**Database** `PSQL`

Comment: just do `DeviseMultipleTokenAuth`, what's `Device` in the end?

Comment: have you generated/created model for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for the same is, we've to create a file called `devise_multiple_token_auth_device.rb` in app/models/

**here is the code for *devise_multiple_token_auth_device.rb* file**

```
class DeviseMultipleTokenAuthDevice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```